# Jquery addRemove Class - If statement

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I need when I click Toggle for the jQuery to remove .hidesome and change it to .show and vise versa.

Can not get this...it's been 4 hours of searching.

```
<a href="#" class="button">Toggle</a>
<div class="signatureContain">
<div class="signature hidesome">
    When the button above is pressed you should see the rest<br />
    "the rest"
</div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="button">Toggle</a>
<div class="signatureContain">
<div class="signature hidesome">
    When the button above is pressed you should see the rest<br />
    "the rest"
</div>
</div>


('.signatureContain').live('click',function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('hidesome'))
      {
         $(this).removeClass('hidesome');
         $(this).addClass('show');
      } else
      {
         $(this).removeClass('show')
         $(this).addClass('hidesome');
      }
});


.hidesome{ height:20px;overflow:hidden}
.show{ height:auto }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w3Hg3/

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()`  to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()`  in preference to `.live()`.

Comment: [jQuery.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: You're also missing $ at the start of your selector: $('.signatureContain')

Comment: I'm editing with XenForo software that is running 1.5.3. I only need it compatible with that, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and advice. It's still not working.

Comment: and your jsfiddle doesn't work as you need to include jQuery Framework onload (see menu on left side)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.toggleClass`, but I think you're a little bit off on a lot of the rest of your code.  Instead of binding to `.signatureContain` you probably want to bind to `.button` and find the *sibling* `.signatureContain` and then its `.signature` child.  You're also missing the `$`.  I fixed all of that here:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3Hg3/3/

`.toggleClass` version: http://jsfiddle.net/w3Hg3/5/

Comment: I tried on() and delegate(). Neither worked. Updated code:
http://jsfiddle.net/w3Hg3/6/

Comment: @GCSkye http://jsfiddle.net/w3Hg3/7/ -- `.on` is on jQuery 1.7+.  Not sure why `.delegate` wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method.

```
$('.signatureContain').on('click', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass("hidesome show");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the event listener to the button and not to the container .signatureContain

```
$('a.button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).next('.signatureContain').children('.signature').toggleClass('show');
});
```

.on is better in performance than live: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/

by using children you can specific more than with find.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3H4ym/